# Add/del root user Linux mint 19

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Достался ящик от предыдущего сотрудника, стоит Линукс минт 19. Могу я как-то создать нового рут пользователя и потом удалить старого? Лень сносить минту. Действующий пароль естественно уехал вместе с хозяином.

Comment: Пароль меняется через GRUB. Google в помощь.

Comment: надо не удалять (записи в /etc/passwd + /etc/shadow + /etc/group), а всего лишь сменить пароль. но с большой вероятностью даже этого не потребуется, если есть право пользоваться программой sudo.

Comment: написал же, что пароль от судо уехал вместе с предыдущим хозяином. а по факту, да, просто поменял пароль, имя пользователя и хоста, и имя папки хоум. от старого пользователя не осталось и следа.